# Seeking function to calculate mean for missing or NA values in dataframe using R?

Tags: r, data-frame

I am trying to develop a function that will calculate a mean lat/long for my missing or zeros location (lat/long) data in my dataset.

I have locations for many SETS within the same TRIP, which tends to be close in space. However, in many cases, I am missing the location information for some of my SETS. I would like to replace these NAs or Zeros values with the mean lat/long calculated from the remaining SETS within that TRIP.

```
> head(newdata[,c(3,12,26:27)])#This is my data
        TRIP_ID SET_NO SH_LATITUDE SH_LONGITUDE
13365 100020848      3    41.88983    -66.29183
13373 100020848      6    41.93317    -66.29767
13430 100020848     11    42.01200    -66.45217
13442 100020848      7    41.92383    -66.29733
23207 100020848      4    41.94817    -66.29750
24669 100020848      9    41.88300    -66.30567
```

So for example, SH_LONGITUDE has 17239 SET_NO with missing values from different TRIP_ID.

```
> look<-newdata[newdata$SH_LONGITUDE==0,]
> dim(look)
[1] 17239   130
> head(table(look$TRIP_ID))

100020997 100021109 100021204 100021306 100021337 100021340 
        1         2         1         1         2         1
```

I am a newbie with user-defined functions, but this is what I would like to be able to call for.

```
replacebymean<-function(dat, x...?) {
    if dat[dat$x==0, ] or dat[is.na(dat$x), ] 
    then "find these NAs/zeros associated TRIP_ID" and 
          calculate the mean lat/long for each TRIP_ID as  
             mean(dat$x[dat$TRIP_ID=="e.g.,100022478"], na.rm=T) and 
          replace these NAs/zeros by this mean value.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd replace zero and NA values with trip means:

```
# Strings ain't factors
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Set up some fake data
fakedat <- data.frame(trip_id = c(rep("Trip A", 10), rep("Trip B", 10)),
                      set_no = c(1:10, 1:10),
                      sh_lat = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 41, sd = 1),
                      sh_long = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 66, sd = 1)
)


# Set a few in each trip to zero and NA
fakedat$sh_lat[c(3, 7, 17)] <- 0
fakedat$sh_lat[c(6, 14, 20)] <- NA
fakedat$sh_long[c(4, 5, 13)] <- 0
fakedat$sh_long[c(2, 8, 19)] <- NA


# Function to replace zero and NA by the mean value of the vector
replacebymean <- function(x, replacevals = c(0, NA)) {

    # Get the mean of the vector, excluding the values you intend to replace
    vecmean <- mean(x[!x %in% replacevals])

    # Replace all of those values with the vector mean
    x.fill <- x
    x.fill[x.fill %in% replacevals] <- vecmean

    # Return the filled vector
    x.fill

}


# Use some kind of split-apply-combine to iterate over the trips
# ddply from the plyr package makes it pretty easy to do this in one pass
library(plyr)

filldat <- ddply(.data = fakedat, .var = "trip_id", .fun = function(x) {

    # Inside of the function(x) call, x represents the trip_id subsets - 
    # ddply will take care of the iteration and recombination,
    # you just have to worry about writing code for one subset

    # Fill both lat and long - you could overwrite them instead of making
    # new variables, but this is more transparent
    x$sh_lat_fill <- replacebymean(x$sh_lat)
    x$sh_long_fill <- replacebymean(x$sh_long)

    # Return
    x

})
```

I think this is what you were going for, but I was a little confused by the question. Here are a couple for you:

- Do you actually have records for the sets with missing info?  The
  discontinuity of the set numbers in your example data makes me wonder
  if you aren't missing entire records - quite a different problem.
- "Trip" implies sequential visits, in which case it might make more difference to average the adjacent sets.  For example, if the Set 5 latitude was missing, would it make more sense to take the average of the latitudes of Sets 4 and 6?

Comment: Thank you @Matt Parker for this answer! To answer you question 1) Yes, I do, but I also have a lot of missing records for sets. 2) Agreed, it would make a lot of sense to average lat/long of the adjacent sets. However, might be difficult to do since I'm missing a lot of records. Would you have suggestions?

Comment: @GodinA I think that your best bet in that regard would be to start thinking of your data as two correlated time series.  I don't have much experience with time series data myself, but the topic of missing data in time series comes up a lot.  Check out [this search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+series+missing) on stats.stackexchange.com - I think that'll get you started, at least.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the is.na function to select for values which are NA. Eg :

```
> t<-c(1:10,NA,1:5)
> t
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA  1  2  3  4  5
> mean(t)
[1] NA
> mean(t, na.rm=T)
[1] 4.666667
> t[is.na(t) ]<-mean(t, na.rm=T)
> t
 [1]  1.000000  2.000000  3.000000  4.000000  5.000000  6.000000  7.000000
 [8]  8.000000  9.000000 10.000000  4.714286  1.000000  2.000000  3.000000
[15]  4.000000  5.000000
```

So in your case:

`dat$x[dat$TRIP_ID=="e.g.,100022478"&is.na(dat$x)] <-mean(dat$x[dat$TRIP_ID=="e.g.,100022478"], na.rm=T)`

You could use a loop to iterate over your TRIP_ID values:

```
for(trip in unique(dat$TRIP_ID)){
dat$x[dat$TRIP_ID==trip&is.na(dat$x)] <-mean(dat$x[dat$TRIP_ID==trip], na.rm=T)
}
```